# Google App Engine PHP requests seem to always go to the catch all handler

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, cloud

I am new to google app engine and am using PHP to create a website for a project on google app engine. The website will need to have multiple files. At the moment I am able to go on one page and when I click the 'contact' link to go to the contact page, the page still says the same and doesn't change.

My app.yaml handlers are:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: /.*    
  script: mainpage.php    

- url: /contact.php     
  script: contact.php
```

So I can go to mainpage.php and when I click on the 'contact' link, the URL chances to ****.appspot.com/contact.php. But the page doesn't actually change to 'contact.php'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert your handlers. The way handlers work is that it looks top to bottom, as soon as there's ONE match, it returns that.

So if your first handler is a catch all, there is no way to go to the second one :)

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. Thank you. So how would both handlers look?

Comment: The same way, just inverse them. Put your main one AFTER the contact one